# Match exacltly n numeric digits Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to use regex to match a string of exactly 2 characters, and both of those characters have to be between 0 and 9.

Example: if I provide 12  - True and if I provide 123- it should give false.

I have tried below examples.

\d{6}$

^[0-9]{2}$

However, Even I enter 123, it is giving as true but I need it as false as I need exactly two.

Comment: `^[0-9]{2}$` is correct. How did you use it?

Comment: Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6d3tstp0/), only `12` is matched. Your second regex works as per the requirements.

Answer (score -1):

try this regex

^\d\d$

test here https://www.regextester.com/1966

Comment: Yes, but If I have 123 then it should return as false

Answer (score -1):

Using ^[0-9]{2}$ you get a number between 0 and 9 and then two digits.

If you only want two digits can use \d{2}

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way is to use `wc -l` to count the amount of charecters.
i.e:

```
NUM=123

if [[ `echo ${NUM} | wc -l` -gt 2 ]];then
  echo "You provided a number grater than 2 digits"
  exit 1
fi
```